# Escaping special characters in bash

Tags: java, bash, jar

I have this command in a bash script:

```
sudo java -jar ./myjar.jar name_%1$tY%1$tm.csv ./sql/blablab.sql someArgument
```

or

```
sudo java -jar ./myjar.jar "name_%1$tY%1$tm.csv" ./sql/blablab.sql someArgument
```

Any of these two commands will yield these 3 arguments:

```
Arguments :   name_%1%1.csv  ./sql/blablab.sql  someArgument
```

As you can see, `%` and/or `$` did not get escaped. I'm looking for a way to escape them.

Best regards

Comment: Im not sure but try with 2 % signs like name_%%1$tY%%1$tm.csv . let me know if it works

Answer (score 4, accepted):

In bash a non-quoted backslash `\` is the escape character. It preserves the literal value of the next character that follows, with the exception of `\n`. You don't need to escape the `%` character but you do have to escape the `$` or bash will consider it a variable and expand it.

In your case,

```
sudo java -jar ./myjar.jar name_%1\$tY%1\$tm.csv ./sql/blablab.sql someArgument
```

should work.

Answer (score 2):

Try this:

```
sudo java -jar ./myjar.jar 'name_%1$tY%1$tm.csv' ./sql/blablab.sql someArgument
```

This is assuming that you want to all `$` characters unescaped to `java`. There's other ways:

```
example_$notAVar$aVar    # yields example_
example_\$notAVar\$aVar  # yields example_$notAVar$aVar
aVar=42
example_$notAVar$aVar    # yields example_42
'example_$notAVar$aVar'  # yields example_$notAVar$aVar
"example_\$notAVar$aVar" # yields example_$notAVar42
example_\$notAVar$aVar   # yields example_$notAVar42
'example_$notAVar'$aVar  # yields example_$notAVar42
```